# php max value of array in while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get the max value of an array which is inside a while loop and bind this value to a variable but when I try I get multiple results, not just one.

Here's an example of first table where I get the current values I need to compare with the second table;

```
tbl name: table1
----------------------------
| id |  type   |  category | 
|----|---------|-----------|
| 1  |  apple  |  red      |  
|----|---------|-----------|
| 3  |  orange |  yellow   | 
|----|---------|-----------|
| 4  |  orange |  red      |  
----------------------------
```

Here's an example of the second table where I compare the current values of the first table in order to find out the amount;

```
tbl name: table2
-------------------------------------
| id |  type   |  category | amount |
|----|---------|-----------|--------|
| 1  |  apple  |  red      |  50.00 |
|----|---------|-----------|--------|
| 2  |  apple  |  green    |  75.00 |
|----|---------|-----------|--------|
| 3  |  orange |  yellow   |  20.00 |
|----|---------|-----------|--------|
| 4  |  orange |  red      |  20.00 |
-------------------------------------
```

Here's my code;

```
$select_table1  = "select * from table1";
$connect_table1 = mysqli_query($con, $select_table1);
while ($row_table1 = mysqli_fetch_array($connect_table1)) {
    $type     = $row_table1['type'];
    $category = $row_table1['category'];

    $select_table2  = "select * from table2 where type in('$type') and category in('$category')";
    $connect_table2 = mysqli_query($con, $select_table2);
    while ($row_table2 = mysqli_fetch_array($connect_table2)) {
        $amount = array(
            $row_table2['amount']
        );
        $max    = max($amount);
        echo "$max<br/>";
    }
}
```

This gives me;

```
50.00
20.00
20.00
```

I just need the highest amount on its own which is 50.00
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is the output you want? Just `50.00`? Based on what, isn't the green apple higher of value?

Comment: Also note that using a query within a query can usually be avoided by using a join.

Comment: yes, exactly. The 3 rows contained in the first table to compare with the second table to get the single highest value.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: You need to move your max($amount) function out of the loop and collect the $row_table2['amount'] values in a separate array, like $amounts[] =  $row_table2['amount']. After you have collected your values in that array, you can call and echo your max() function. Besides from that you could already retrieve the highest value right from the DB by using a Sort-By-Limit Combination or a Select Max Clause.

Comment: @tadman there's no user input here at all, no post or get, I'm simply comparing values from 2 tables. If there was I'd be using prepared statements.

Comment: You're injecting data from the database without any escaping whatsoever. If you *assume* these are safe that's when you have huge problems. Where does `category` come from? That could be user input. **Use prepared statements for all values**, not just the ones you think are unsafe. Keep your data and query completely separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks for the ideas here, I got this solved using the following. It may be more convoluted than the answer from @Qirel but there were extra complications I didn't mention as I didn't want to create a mess. For instance these tables are from 2 separate databases which use specific connections and I had to rely on variables as the data in the first table is user created and retrieved based on the value of a cookie.

Thanks to @rpm192, it was almost there.

```
<?php
$select_table1 = "select * from table1";
$connect_table1 = mysqli_query($con, $select_table1);
     while ($row_table1 = mysqli_fetch_array($connect_table1)) {
     $type = $row_table1['type'];
     $category = $row_table1['category'];

     $select_table2  = "select * from table2 where type in('$type') and category in('$category')";
     $connect_table2 = mysqli_query($con, $select_table2);
     while ($row_table2 = mysqli_fetch_array($connect_table2)) {
          $amount = $row_table2['amount'];
          $myArray[] = $amount;
     }
}
$maxAmount = max($myArray);
echo $maxAmount;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `JOIN` combined with the aggregate function `MAX()` to get your result. This will instead perform one single query, and no additional PHP logic required.

```
$query = 'SELECT MAX(t2.amount) as maxAmount
          FROM table2 t2
          JOIN table1 t1
            ON t1.type = t2.type
              AND t1.category = t2.category';
$query = $con->query($query);
$result = $query->fetch_assoc();
echo $result['maxAmount'];
```

. See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55419d/2)